# SP13 - How to Get the Selected Date/Time within SharePoint Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part, sharepoint-calendar

I Create Visual Web Part for SharePoint Calendar (New form). I have needs to retrieve clicked date in sharepoint calendar.

**How to do this:**

[image]

Thank you previusly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we click “Add” in a date column in SharePoint Calendar, the default value of “Start Time” and “End Time” in the opened New Form will be the selected date.

[image]

To get the selected date, we can get the default “Start Time/End Time” and set the Title to its value using JavaScript in New Form.

Add the following script to the page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    var date = $('[id$="DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate"]').val();
    $("input[title='Title']").val(date);
  }, 200);  
})
</script>
```